# How to refresh a query table with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am using query table to call in a csv file to a particular sheet. I want this to refresh say every 30 seconds. I have the following code to call in the csv file but I cannot see to get the refresh to work. The code runs, puts the csv data into the correct worksheet but it doesn't seem to refresh Can anybody point me in the write direction please? It's a little embarrassing because I sort of code in Python and MATLAB but with VBA I struggle to grasp it. Thanks for your help

```
Dim fileName As String
fileName = "C:\Users\aofarrell\Desktop\Book1.csv"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet8").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & fileName, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        '.Name = "CAPTURE"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0.5
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True


    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like a bit of an XY problem - why do you need to refresh a query from a CSV every 30 seconds?

Comment: The csv file is changing very frequently, it a couple of times a second to once an hour.. so having a regular refresh is what I'd like. I did think about running the code on a loop every 30s but I imagine that's probably not the best way to go! What do you think?

Comment: If you use a PowerQuery (Get and Transform in Data Ribbon) conform Excel Version you should use PowerQuery to import the CSV Data. For the Query you can set the refreshtime to 30 Sec.  That’s much easier and VBA free.

Comment: @Chris can you clarify how I do this - in particular when I use powerquery the only way I know to set the refresh rate is from the query properties where the refresh rate is given in minutes and you have to enter an integer therefore you cannot go less than a minute. Do you know another way round this?

Comment: @AidanO'Farrell: Yes your right. Thats only possible with full minutes. I think to refresh a PQ Query every x-seconds you must also use vba by using ```Application.OnTime``` ... so it`s not VBA-free.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution to this?